# Problems Configuring mod_wsgi with Virtual Env

Tags: python, django, apache

I am struggling trying to get Apache 2.4.7 to serve a Django 1.8.17 application using mod_wsgi 4.5.15 with Python 3.5.3 as a virtual environment.  This is the only virtual environment I have on the machine (Linux Mint 17.3).

I am getting an "internal Server Error" in the browser.

My Apache error log says:

```
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:22.530935 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4476] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21 mod_wsgi/4.5.15 Python/3.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:22.531008 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4476] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.165360 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901] mod_wsgi (pid=4480): Target WSGI script '/home/magic-rat/ektropy_project/ektropy_project/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.165494 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901] mod_wsgi (pid=4480): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/magic-rat/ektropy_project/ektropy_project/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166150 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166210 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]   File "/home/magic-rat/ektropy_project/ektropy_project/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166218 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166230 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]   File "/home/magic-rat/virtualenvs/ektropy_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166238 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]     django.setup()
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166250 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]   File "/home/magic-rat/virtualenvs/ektropy_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166257 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166269 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]   File "/home/magic-rat/virtualenvs/ektropy_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166276 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]     self._setup(name)
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166288 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]   File "/home/magic-rat/virtualenvs/ektropy_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166295 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166307 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]   File "/home/magic-rat/virtualenvs/ektropy_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166314 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166325 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166335 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166347 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166358 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166369 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166381 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166392 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166418 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166429 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Thu Apr 06 19:48:28.166464 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4480] [remote 127.0.0.1:34901] ImportError: No module named 'ektropy_project'
```

My directory structure is:

```
home/magic-rat/
|
|__________virtualenvs
|               |
|               |-ektropy_project
|                        |
|                        |-lib
|                           |
|                           |-python3.5
|                                |
|                                |-site_packages
|
|__________ektropy_project   
                  |
                  |-manage.py
                  |
                  |-ektropy_project
                           |
                           |-wsgi.py
                           |-helloworld.wsgi (so you can see where it is)
```

My Apache Virtual host file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

WSGIDaemonProcess ektropy_project python-home=/home/magic-rat/virtualenvs/ektropy_project

WSGIProcessGroup ektropy_project
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/magic-rat/ektropy_project/ektropy_project/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/magic-rat/ektropy_project/ektropy_project>
    <Files wsgi.py>
       Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

My wsgi.py file is:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ektropy_project.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I believe mod_wsgi is configured properly.  I can run a simple hello_world program and it works.

I believe permissions are set properly on all the files.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your nginx looks fine, because you get Django error log. Did you test your app without nginx (`python manage.py runserver`)? I think it is strange, because looks you didn't add the main module to your settings...

Comment: Yes, it works great with the built in runserver command.  I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra option to `WSGIDaemonProcess` of:

```
python-path=/home/magic-rat/ektropy_project
```

You have to tell mod_wsgi where your project code is as well so it can import it.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!  

I'm getting the dynamic content and some, of the .css.  I'll go figure that out now.

I'm finally up with Apache!

Comment: For static files see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files